# Name field creating middle name partial from first name

Tags: formula-field, fields, field-update

I'm hoping to get some guidance around a confusing bug in my salesforce.
For some reason, and I can't figure out why, the Name field continues to create a middle name partially from the first name.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the standard `Name` field on `Lead` and `Contact`, it's something like a formula field. It's read-only, and [documentation tells us](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) that it is

> Concatenation of FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix up to 203 characters, including whitespaces.

So your record here must have "liam" in the `MiddleName` field (which does not appear to be on your page layout). How exactly it got there, we don't have enough information to say. The record could've been created like that, or you could have a workflow rule, record-triggered flow, process builder, flow, or a trigger in your org that is doing that.

The easiest way to get rid of it would be to query the record via the developer console, clear out the `MiddleName` field, and click the "save rows" button.

Comment: Thanks Derek!

I had a look through and there is not flow etc interfering. 

I also attempted to query the record via the developer console but I can't find any middle name.

It has got me really stumped